# If we install the apk outside the Play Store, does it affect Google Play statistics?

Tags: google-play-store

If we install the apk outside the Play Store, does it affect Google Play statistics?

Answer (score 1):

NO, apps installed outside Google Play do not affect statistics.

Those apps are considered to be coming from `Unknown sources`,
and you cannot install them if you do not manually allow (or check) them in
`Settings > Security > Unknown sources`.